# C++ initialize reference with expression at constructor

Tags: c++

Consider the following C++ classes:

```
// An abstract fruit that can be sliced
class AbstractFruit
{
public:
  virtual void Slice() = 0;
};

// A lemon (concrete implementation of AbstractFruit)
class Lemon : public AbstractFruit
{
int size; // small medium large

public:
  Lemon(int size) : size(size) {}
  virtual void Slice() override { /* slice it */ }
};

// A pie uses a fruit reference
class Pie
{
  AbstractFruit& fruit;

public:
  Pie(AbstractFruit& fruit) : fruit(fruit) {}  
};
```

This all works fine.

For backwards compatibility reasons, the Pie API needs to have a constructor that creates a lemon pie:

```
Pie(int size) : fruit(Lemon(size)) {}
```

This doesn't work. To the best of my understanding, I'm creating a new Lemon instance in the parameter list of the constructor and initializing the fruit reference with it. But, the Lemon instance gets destructed immediately after that, leaving the fruit reference pointing to a destroyed object.

What's the best way to make this work?

I understand I could switch the Pie to use a pointer instead of a reference, but I'd like to use a reference if possible.

Comment: from a cooking stand point, there is no reason for the pie to store the fruit as reference, as it take ownership on it.

Comment: not related: consider using a different name for member variale and parameters: this `fruit(fruit)` is so unreadable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size of `Pie` object is not critical, one possible solution is to let `Pie` manage optional `Lemon`:

```
class Pie
{
    std::optional<Lemon> lemon_;
    AbstractFruit& fruit_;

public:
    Pie(AbstractFruit& fruit) : fruit_(fruit) {}
    Pie(int size) : lemon_(size), fruit_(*lemon_) {}
};
```

`std::optional` is optional, `std::unique_ptr` can be used instead:

```
class Pie
{
    std::unique_ptr<Lemon> lemon_;
    AbstractFruit& fruit_;

public:
    Pie(AbstractFruit& fruit) : fruit_(fruit) {}
    Pie(int size) : lemon_(std::make_unique<Lemon>(size)), fruit_(*lemon_) {}
};
```

In the first case, `Lemon` will be stored inside `Pie` itself, in the second case, `Lemon` will be allocated on heap, and `Pie` will store only a pointer to it. If `Lemon` size is small (<= `sizeof(void*)`), `std::optional` is a better option.

Note that the members are [initialized in order of declaration in the class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order), that's why `lemon_` declaration should come before `fruit_` one.

Comment: I am trying the solution with `std::unique_ptr` but it doesn't seem to work. `lemon_` is correctly initialized, but `fruit_` isn't. Hovering over `fruit_` in the debugger says `<struct at NULL>`.

Comment: @NikolaosGeorgiou, I don't see any problem: https://godbolt.org/z/vt8Dhv Note the order of initialization: `lemon_`, then `fruit_`.

Comment: Wow great site, I didn't know about it. Unfortunately, I can reproduce my problem also on that site with your code. I added the `Slice` method. When I call `pie.lemon_->Slice()` it works. When I call `pie.fruit_.Slice()` it crashes. https://godbolt.org/z/fbZsVQ

Comment: @NikolaosGeorgiou, I fixed the error. `lemon_` should precede `fruit_` to be initialized before it.

Comment: Oh! So the order of the field declaration on the class itself makes a difference! Do you know by any chance if there is some documentation on how this works? Thank you for your help, I think your solution is great.

Comment: @NikolaosGeorgiou, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order

Answer (score 1):

A reference is just a memory address, either 32-bit or 64-bit. Where should the actual bytes of your `Lemon` live after you have finished calling the constructor?

Currently they live in the stack, which is cleaned up after you finish calling the constructor. To avoid this you need to provide some other storage location for your `Lemon` which lives at least as long as your `Pie`.

The easiest way to do this is to use `new` to allocate `Lemon` on the heap, and then decide when you are going to clean it up later.

Comment: I still need both constructors of `Pie`. The one that accepts the reference to the abstract `Fruit` class and the one that accepts the lemon size.

How will the two constructors look like in that case?

Comment: You can keep both constructors. You just need to provide storage for the Lemon object that the `int size` overload creates.